# If AD Description has certain number add to a specified group

Tags: powershell

I have a script I'm trying to expand on to create student accounts from a csv. Works great.

What I'm looking for:

- If the **description** has the following number: 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06 add to. **K-6 Students** member group.
- If the **description** has the following numbers: 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, or 12 add to **6-12 Students** member group.
- In addition to the **All-Students** group listed below.

Account example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7MFD.jpg

Here is part of the script I'm using

```
 New-ADUser -Name "$Displayname" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName "$UserFirstname" -Surname "$UserLastname" -Description "$Description" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false –PasswordNeverExpires $true -Enabled $true -server AD1.schoolname.k12.or.us -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory -HomeDrive $HomeDrive 

    Add-ADGroupMember -identity All-Students -members $SAM -server AD1.schoolname.k12.or.us

    Write-Host "AD Account $Displayname created!"  

    add-content $SuccessLog  "User $Displayname created Sucessfully."

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $Displayname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to sort your students:

```
$students = Get-ADUser -Filter "Description -like '*0*' -or Description -like '*1*'" -Properties Description
$studentsK6 = $students | Where Description -match '0[1-6]'
$students712 = $students | Where Description -match '0[7-9]|1[0-2]'

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'K-6 Students' -Members $studentsK6.SamAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity '6-12 Students' -Members $students712.SamAccountName
```

**Explanation:**

`-Filter` is used to help narrow down the user search, and it is typically faster than piping to `Where-Object`.

`-Properties Description` is used to ensure that `$students` contains the `Description` property so we can compare against it later. By default, the `ADUser` object does not show the `Description` property with the default output view.

`0[1-6]` matches any two-digit number that begins with 0 and ends with 1,2,3,4,5, or 6.

`0[7-9]|1[0-2]` first attempts to match 0 followed by a 7,8, or 9. If that fails, it will try matching 1 followed by 0,1, or 2.

You can make the matching more reliable if you know exactly where the number exists in the `Description`. For example, if it is always at the end of the `Description`, you can use `0[1-6]$` where `$` matches the end of a string.

Comment: +1 to advising a proper LDAP filter and using `-match` sensibly to refine the results. The only thing to add is `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'All-Students' -Members  $students.SamAccountName`, but that could have been inferred easily ;)